# c++ queue pop without push

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I am using lot of `std::queue<uint32_t> Queue` on my c++ runtime application. 
I need to understand, what will be the maximum number of values I can push into the queue and what will happen if I **pop_front()** with any **push_back()**.

Sometimes my code breaks inside a thread when trying to pop a value.

```
PostEvent(uint32_t EventUid)
{
    /* Create Event Thread only when 
       first event received (E_RESTART.COLD) */
    if (!isThreadCreated) {
        c_thread::start("event");
        isThreadCreated = true;
    }

    Queue.push_back(EventUid);
}
```

event_thread::run():

```
while (isThreadAlive())
{
    while (Queue.size())
    {
        if (!Queue.empty())
        {
            uint32_t EventUid;
            EventUid = Queue[0];
            Queue.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I need to know, can I use data structure like

```
struct Counter_Elements
{
    uint32_t              eventId;
    std::string           applicationName;
    std::string           functionName;
    std::string           dataName; 
    std::string           dataValue;
    uint64_t              count;
    char                  tag;
};
```

and create a queue like `std::queue<Counter_Elements> CountQueue`. If so what will be the max number of counter elements that I can push.

Comment: Recommend some mutex protection for that queue.

Comment: This looks like a concurrency issue. Are you familiar with concepts like mutexes and condition variables?

Answer (score 0):

The standard containers are only thread-safe for read-only situations. You'll want to use (for example) a mutex to protect the queue while you modify it (pushing and/or popping).

Typically you'd want to start by creating your thread-safe queue, something like this:

```
template <class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> 
class ts_queue {
    Container c;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    void push(T const &v) { 
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
       c.push_back(v); 
    }

    bool pop(T &v) { 
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);

       if (c.empty())
           return false;

       v = c.front();
       c.pop_front();
       return true;
    }
};
```

This way, only one thread can modify the queue at any given time, keeping the queue safe.

Note that I've changed the signature of `pop` to one I've found (much) more useful when doing multi-threaded programming. In a typical case, you want to add a time-out to the pop (and maybe the push as well) so if no data is available in a reasonable length of time, you just give up and return false. As it stands now, this does a simplified version of that, returning false if data isn't available immediately.